# What does "2N363PNP" mean?

Tags: transistors, bjt

Recently I did the experiment of input and output characteristics of BJT and I saw that "2N363PNP" was written on it.I want to know what does it mean? Is it only a name ?I can guess that it is a PNP transistor but what does 2N363 mean?

Comment: 2N363 is the part number of the PNP transistor.

Comment: These part numbers are typically used in the USA.

Comment: 1N.... for diodes, 2N.... for transistors.

Answer (score 2):

2N363 is the part number for a TO-5 germanium PNP BJT. The closest equivalent you're likely to find in any quantity is NTE102.

Comment: Please can you explain what part number is ?

Comment: It's a manufacturer (or supplier/user) defined identifier for a part. Sometimes it has some extra meaning. For example, Analog Device's [AD854](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8541_8542_8544.pdf) series op-amp can be an AD8541 for a single amp, AD8542 for a double amp, or AD8544 for a quad amp. However, there is no "standard" way to interpret a part number as pretty much everyone has their own way (though you recognize a few patterns the more you see them).

Comment: @souravchakraborty The reason they're not on the shelf at distributors is that they were probably introduced between 50 and 60 years ago, and have been obsolete for many decades (replaced with much better performing and cheaper parts).

Comment: One just has to stop and think that if the op is still using a 50 year old part in experiments how reliable electronics are in general. On the flip side how much money this part has generated in that time. Really amazes me everytime.